# Why does Mr Weasley say this?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, 7th Chapter, Mr Weasley says, "Harry, please. You are talking to the man who raised Fred and George."

What does this statement mean? Does Mr Weasley know that Harry gave Fred and George his Triwizard Tournament winnings?

Comment: -1 since the question lacks research. Arthur was simply talking about the disappearance of the trio from the shop.

Comment: @Shreedhar - I would imagine that it's more of an English comprehension issue than a lack of research.

Comment: @Valorum English Comprehension issue on whose part  ? ME or MR WESLEY  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter - On your part

Comment: Who „raised“ Fred and George: not „funded“. He means himself as the father who raised them and therefor knows all about kids on the run (agree with valorum: you might wanna check your dictionary for the translation of „raised“)

Answer (score 14):

Mr Weasley is telling Harry that he isn't in the least bit surprised that the golden trio sneaked out of the place they were supposed to be, so that they could go off adventuring. Evidently Fred and George did this from an early age, as evidenced by their continuing to do so once they reached Hogwarts.

> ‘When we were in Diagon Alley –’ Harry began, but Mr Weasley forestalled him with a grimace.
>
> ‘Am I about to discover where you, Ron and Hermione disappeared to while you were supposed to be in the back room of Fred and George’s shop?’
>
> ‘How did you –?’ ***[know that we left without your permission]***
>
> ‘Harry, please. You’re talking to the man who raised Fred and George.’ ***[...And hence is fully aware that you didn't stay put, despite being told to]***
>
> ‘Er … yeah, all right, we weren’t in the back room.’